# Pulling RSS from site and display it in posts

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, shortcode, rss

I'm trying to pull rss from sites similar to this: http://andreabadendyck.blogg.no/

I have several posts with the URL in the title, so I can pull the URLS from here and hardcode the rss reader in the theme.

I want to display the recent posts like this (under "Siste innlegg"): http://blogglisten.no/blogg/andreabadendyck.blogg.no

Is it any available plugins for this? I have tried RSS Feed Reader for WordPress with no luck.

Comment: Try [FeedWordPress](http://feedwordpress.radgeek.com/)

Comment: This makes new posts. I only want to display the recent posts inside my posts. Like this page under "Siste innlegg": http://blogglisten.no/blogg/bibses.blogg.no

Comment: Well what you're actually wanting to do is show a loop of pulled in content - so FeedWordPress would work pretty well for that.

Comment: It seems to not be working: http://feedwordpress.radgeek.com/wiki/how-do-i-make-new-posts-my-feeds-appear-separate-page-instead-being-imported-main-stream-posts

Comment: did you read the very first comment on the wiki page you linked to?

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't fit the purpose. This helped me on the way: http://digwp.com/2009/11/import-and-display-feeds-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed this guide to insert the feed in the post: http://digwp.com/2009/11/import-and-display-feeds-in-wordpress/

My only problem is that I need to strip away the HTML from the feed.